# How to set tag for 'KeyPressFcn' callbackfunction

Tags: matlab, callback

I have the followig set function which gets the current key (here f my figure handle which displays my plots) and displays it

```
set(f, 'KeyPressFcn', @getkeyvalue)
   function getkeyvalue(source,callbackdata)
      cur_charac = get(source,'CurrentCharacter') 
   end
```

when I press the key it selects the subplots according to order of the key pressed and applies a ginput on it Now i have to share this `cur_charac` with another callback function , a recommended method by matlab is [defined here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) , but the problem is it is defining tags in in the `uicontrol()` and then finding the tag from `findobj('Tag','anyTag');` and retrieving the data , my problem is how can I define a tag for my 'KeyPressFcn' callback so I can retrive the data

Comment: You don't define tags for callbacks, you define them for graphics objects. Use the methods you already linked to store the data to the graphics object and use the tag to find the graphics object if you can't pass the object directly. The documentation explains all of this clearly.

Comment: The problem is I am not using any graphics object directly I check the key and perform a ginput for the selected subplot and now I have to pass this key to another callback function that is also not a graphics object

Comment: One method would be to define the cur_charac global but thats not way i want to go

Comment: You *can't* have a `KeyPressFcn` without a graphics object. What is `f`? I suggest creating a [mcve] because I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: f is a handle for my Plot actually

Comment: I will edit my post

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working? The [first example in the documentation you linked](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html#buz2lns) goes through this exact process.

Comment: The first exaple is getting through h = findobj('Tag','slider1'); and then getting through the tag data = h.UserData; I dont have a tag please go through the example again

Comment: I suggest you heed your own advice and go through the example again and read what I have already told you. Tags are properties of graphics objects, not callbacks. Specify a tag for your figure window. In `getkeyvalue` you have the handle, `source`, to your figure window. Use that to store your data (like the example does). In your other callback function get the handle to your figure window by searching for its tag (like the example does). Use the handle to get the data (like the example does).